# Why does the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor increase on filling it with an insulating dielectric if the voltage is fixed?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage, capacitance, dielectric

In the case that the electric field $\textbf{E}_0$ is confined to the space between the plates of an isolated and charged parallel-plate capacitor, an inserted linear dielectric that fills the space would reduce $\textbf{E}_0$ and as a consequence the potential difference $\Delta \text{V}_0$ between them, by a factor of $\frac{1}{\kappa}$, where $\kappa$ is the dielectric constant, because $|\textbf{E}| = \text{E}$ and $\Delta \text{V}$ are related linearly as $\Delta \text{V} = \text{E} \times \text{d}$. The charge on either plate is unaffected, simply because it has nowhere to go.

Hence, because $\Delta \text{V}_0 \rightarrow \frac{1}{\kappa} \times \Delta \text{V}_0$, we have $\text{C}_0 = \frac{\text{Q}_0}{\Delta \text{V}_0} \rightarrow \kappa \times \text{C}_0$

Now if the voltage between the plates is held fixed with the use of a source like a battery, regardless of the dielectric constant, $\Delta \text{V}_0$ (and hence $\text{E}_0 = \frac{\Delta \text{V}_0}{\text {d}}$) are unchaged. The capacitance still increases by a factor of $\kappa$, and the explanation is that in this case, $\text{Q}_0 \rightarrow \kappa \times \text{Q}_0$, with the additional charge coming from the wires attached to either plate.

What is the physical explanation behind this? Why does the charge have to increase on either plate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider an extreme case, the insertion of a conductor of thickness $e$ between the plates of a parallel capacitor with separation $d$ and a fixed potential difference of $V$ between them.

Before the insertion the work done in moving unit charge between the plates is $E_{\rm free}\,d = \frac Vd \,d = V$, ie that is the definition of potential difference and also $E_{\rm free} = \dfrac {\sigma_{\rm free}}{\epsilon_0}$.

What happens when the conductor is inserted?

Surface charge $\sigma_{\rm induced} = \sigma' _{\rm free}$ is induced on the conductor such that the electric field inside the conductor is zero.
Now what is the work done moving unit charge between the two plates of the capacitor?

The work done is $E'_{\rm free}\,(d-e) + 0\, e= E'_{\rm free}\,(d-e)$, but this must equal $V$, and since $d-e<d$ then the electric field due to the free charge density on the capacitor plates, $\sigma' _{\rm free}$, must increase, which in turn means that the charge on the capacitor plates must increase.

As a check if the charges on the plates before and after the insertion are $Q_{\rm free}$ and $Q'_{\rm free}$ respectively then,
$V=\dfrac{Q_{\rm free}}{A\epsilon_0}\cdot d = \dfrac{Q'_{\rm free}}{A\epsilon_0}\cdot (d-e) = \dfrac{Q_{\rm free}}{\left(\frac{A\epsilon_0}{d}\right)} = \dfrac{Q'_{\rm free}}{\left(\frac{A\epsilon_0}{(d-e)}\right)}$.

You will then see the familiar equation $V= \dfrac QC$ applied twice, once with no conductor being inserted and the other with the conductor being inserted.

With a dielectric present due to the induced charge (called polarisation) the electric field within the dielectric is reduced but unlike a conductor does not become zero but a similar analysis will show that the charge on the plates of the capacitor must increase to keep the potential difference between the plates constant.

In this case for a well-behaved dielectric, $\sigma_{\rm induced} = \chi\epsilon_0 E_{\rm external}$ and $\kappa = 1+\chi$, where $\chi$ is the electric susceptibility, $\kappa$ the relative permittivity or dielectric constant, and $E_{\rm external}$ is the electric field outside the dielectric.

[Feynman Chapter 10 Dielectrics](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_10.html) is a useful source for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The dielectric is *polarised* by the electric field between the plates. This means that electrons in the molecules are pulled a little towards the positive plate, and nuclei towards the negative plate. The result is that the molecules become dipoles (if they are not already) with their negative ends pointing towards the positive plate.

In the bulk of the dielectric (assumed solid) there is cancellation of effects due to + and — ends of neighbouring dipoles. But the  + plates has the — ends of dipoles next to it, and the – plate has + ends of dipoles next to it. These charges on the surfaces of the dielectric can't neutralise or partly neutralise those on the plates, because they are trapped in the molecules of the dielectric, which makes only imperfect contact with the plates. But for given charges on the plates, they will reduce the electric field strength inside the capacitor, and hence the potential difference between its plates.

But you are asking about what happens when you keep the potential difference the same as before the dielectric was inserted. The only way this can happen is if more charge flows from the battery on to the plates, to compensate for the opposite charges on the adjacent surfaces of the dielectric – which would otherwise reduce the field strength and the pd!

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor increase on
> filling it with an insulating dielectric if the voltage is fixed?

The short answer to the title of your post is the capacitance increases because its dielectric constant is increased. It has nothing to do with the voltage across the capacitor. The capacitance depends only on the physical characteristics of the capacitor (discussed below).

> In the case that the electric field $\textbf{E}_0$ is confined to the
> space between the plates of an isolated and charged parallel-plate
> capacitor, an inserted linear dielectric that fills the space would
> reduce $\textbf{E}_0$ and as a consequence the potential difference
> $\Delta \text{V}_0$ between them,

Correct. Since

$$\frac{Q}{C}=V\tag{1}$$

and given that $Q$ is constant for an isolated capacitor, and increase in capacitance must result in a decreases in the potential difference $V$ across the plates.

> Now if the voltage between the plates is held fixed with the use of a
> source like a battery, regardless of the dielectric constant, $\Delta V_o$ (and hence $\text{E}_0 = \frac{\Delta \text{V}_0}{\text
> {d}}$) are unchanged.

Correct. Since the electric field is the gradient of the voltage, if the voltage and plate separation is unchanged, then the electric field is unchanged.

> The capacitance still increases by a factor of $\kappa$, and the
> explanation is that in this case, $\text{Q}_0 \rightarrow \kappa
> > \times \text{Q}_0$, with the additional charge coming from the wires
> attached to either plate.

The capacitor increases because the dielectric constant of the inserted material is greater than that of free space. Whether or not the capacitor is connected to a fixed voltage source has no bearing on the capacitance, which depends only on its physical characteristics according to, for a parallel plate capacitor:

$$C=\frac{k\epsilon_{o} A}{d}$$

where $k$ is the relative permittivity, or dielectric constant, of the dielectric material, $\epsilon_{o}$ is the permittivity of free space, $A$ is the plate area and $d$ the plate separation. $k=1$ for free space, $k\approx 1$ for air, and $k\gt 1$ for all other media.

"...the additional charge coming from the wires attached to either plate" is in reality the additional net charge on the plates that results from the battery doing work to maintain the voltage across the capacitor when the capacitance increases, per equation 1 above.

Hope this helps.